# Where to start with if I want to learn about wireless technology?

Tags: wireless

I am a mathematics graduate and a government employee. I am pretty good in C and Java programming, understand a lot about computer security and have some good skills in wi-fi hacking.

Now I wanted to broaden my horizons and learn about wireless technology. My main aim is to understand how the satellite TVs work. Almost every aspect of it.

The problem is, I don't know where to start. I don't have an instructor, never attended any lecture on the topic. So I have some questions:

1. Do I have to study the theory of electronics?
2. Do I have to learn embedded systems?
3. How do I get practical knowledge of the system as I don't have access to labs?
4. There are many workshops conducted on robotics, should I participate in those?

Apart from these I don't know what to ask. I can't search for the information on Google as I don't know what to search for.  Any type of suggestion will be appreciated. (I am not intending to make my career in this field, I just want to learn it. I have plenty of time but monetary resources are less. Kindly give your suggestion after taking into account all these things.)

Answer (score 3):

You said:

> My main aim is to understand how the satellite TVs work. Almost every aspect of it.

"Every aspect of it" implies that you need to learn electronics theory, data transmission and encoding, RF and high frequency theory, and probably many other topics.

Think if you were asking a group of aerospace engineers, "I want to learn how a jet works. Every aspect of it."

There are many, many subsystems of a jet. Engines, electronics, aerodynamics, structural and materials engineering, and so on.

While I would wager a jet is more complex than satellite TV, the same problem holds true: There are many underlying layers of knowledge, and you would need to make efforts in each of them to even begin to understand "every aspect" of the overall topic.

Pick an aspect of satellite TV that interests you most, and focus on it. If you dive into the topic and find that you do not understand an underlying concept, you may need to pause your efforts on that topic and gain a better understanding of the foundations.

Once you start to gain knowledge, you will find that you can more easily identify the aspects you do *not* know, and can start to ask better, more focused questions.

Answer (score 1):

Electromagnetic Theory may be a nice start point.
Here is a playlist on youtube, about electromagnetic radiation, and some books.
[Tour of the Electromagnetic Spectrum  by ScienceAtNASA](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lwfJPc-rSXw&list=PL09E558656CA5DF76)
[Satellite Communications, Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071462988)
[Introduction to Satellite Communication, Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1596932104)
I **suggest**, don't do all the job. Writing software, selecting right materials, designing circuit & PCB etc. Focusing on 1 job is better. So, learn the theory, make it secure or crack it on paper, and tell them what to do. But knowledge about software development and electronics let you understand your team members, and speak their language.